# Swift array map with comma before append new value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

i have this following data structure in my Realm object

```
var tags = List<Tag>()
"tags": [
    {
        "tagId": "80069",
        "tagName": "A"
    },
    {
        "tagId": "80070",
        "tagName": "B"
    },
    {
        "tagId": "80071",
        "tagName": "C"
    },
    {
        "tagId": "80073",
        "tagName": "D"
    }
]
```

So what i want to achieve is, I map all my tag name into my new array

this is my code

```
let realmObject = self.realm.objects(MyDTO.self)
let array = Array(realmOutletList).map{Array($0.tags).map{$0.tagName!}.joined(separator: ",")}
```

it prints out this

```
["A,B,C", "A,C,D", "B,C,D"]
```

What I want to achieve is like

```
["A","B","C", "A","C","D", "B","C","D"]
```

I need that kind of array because I am going to create a Set from the array and then compare with another array

The compared array will be like

```
["A","B","C", "A","C","D", "B","C","D"]
```

because of the compared Array and the realmObject Array is different, it always shows false when i use

```
let subset = filterSet.isSubset(of: mySet)
```

Can anyone guide me please??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let's walk through solving the issue:

Consider that you have:

```
let originalArray = ["A,B,C", "A,C,D", "B,C,D"]
```

**First**, we need to separate each string in `originalArray` by "," character, so we could do:

```
let modifiedArray = originalArray.map { $0.components(separatedBy: ",") }
```

We `map` it to transform each string to a strings array (separation).

So far, the output of `modifiedArray` would be:

> [["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "C", "D"], ["B", "C", "D"]]

which is an array of strings array.

**Second**, we need to spilt each -string- array in `modifiedArray` (having one reduced strings array instead), so we could do:

```
var final = [String]()
for array in modifiedArray {
    for string in array {
        final.append(string)
    }
}
```

**OR** by using `reduce`

```
let finalArray = modifiedArray.reduce([], +)
```

Therefore, `finalArray` would be:

> ["A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D"]

which is the desired result.

---

**Conclusion**

For a fully one-lined answer (following the high-order functions approach):

```
let originalArray = ["A,B,C", "A,C,D", "B,C,D"]

let desiredArray = originalArray.map { $0.components(separatedBy: ",") }.reduce([], +)
print(desiredArray) // ["A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Comment: `originalArray` in your answer is wrong result in the question. It's easier to fix problem before it appears, than to apply hack-fix to the failed result.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's quite easy:

This

```
let array = Array(realmOutletList).map{Array($0.tags).map{$0.tagName!}.joined(separator: ",")}
```

should be this

```
let array = Array(realmOutletList).flatMap{Array($0.tags).map{$0.tagName!}}
```

That's all. And you will get your `["A","B","C", "A","C","D", "B","C","D"]`.

Comment: Sir, what if i want to filter it ? so Array(reamOutletList).filter { //continue the mapping }

Comment: @Alvin, filter `tags` arrays or filter `realmOutletList`? Or final result?

Comment: i have to generate array from realmOutletList after filter it. does it make sense to you?

Comment: Then yeah, just put `filter` before `flatMap`.